# C - Reading multiple inputs from terminal for further use in block

Tags: c

So, I need to read multiple numeric (float) inputs from a single line, separated by a single space each, finished with the press of an Enter.

```
These numeric inputs: 50 20 10 5 2 1 0.50 0.20 0.10
```

Further in the .c I would like to be able to store them, make a sum of them, filter them by their value (accepting 50s but filtering out 35s, etc.) and be able to round them up or down, be able to distinguish more than one input of same value..

These are my first couple of weeks in C, so I am not that confident in all the libraries and controls. So far i have tried several various approaches, scanf into multiple floats, scanf into arrays, even gave fgets, strtok and sscanf a shy look after some Q&As here, but with no luck. In general I am looking for a way to execute this in a clean and simple way.

(This is a part of a bigger school project, and just to clarify i am not asking for finished solutions or blocks of code i could just copy, i will be immensely thankful for more of a "point in the right direction" approach..)

Edit: This causes Segmentation fault after input is confirmed with Enter. I understand this has something to do with memory, but have no idea how to resolve it.. also, i feel pretty dumb for using pi as empty slot representation, but i could not come up with anything else. I do not know how many values will be put in, for now i limited it to 5 for testing purposes.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int main(){

int x=0, y=0;
float a[5] = {3.141592};
char buffer[5] = {3.141592};
printf("Input: ");
fgets(buffer, 5, stdin);
while(sscanf(buffer, "%f ", &a[x]) == 1 && !feof(stdin)){
        sscanf(buffer, "%f ", &a[x]);
        x++;
        }
printf("Saved input: ");
while(y<=5 && a[y] != 3.141592){
        printf("%.2f", a[y]);
        y++;
        }
printf("\n");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read the line into a string with `fgets()`, then call `sscanf()` in a loop to read each float.

Comment: Hint: To be able to store them - think of apt data structures. Make up the sum - arithmetic expression + looping statements. Rounding them: <math.h>

Comment: " but with no luck." - you have to show what u tried and we can tell u where you went wrong. Everything you list is a reasonable thing to do

Comment: What is the point that you stumble concretely? For example, if it is "input of indefinite length", use something like [getline](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) or implement something similar. (Probably easier than analyzing each input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your input is `50 20 10 5 2 1 0.50 0.20 0.10`, this line:

```
fgets(buffer, 5, stdin);
```

will read 4 characters into `buffer` (plus a NUL terminator), giving

```
buffer = { '5', '0', ' ', '2', '\0' }
// or equivalently
buffer = "50 2"
```

Then we enter this loop:

```
while(sscanf(buffer, "%f ", &a[x]) == 1 && !feof(stdin)){
```

The `sscanf` call succeeds, placing `50.0` into `a[0]`. `feof(stdin)` is false because the previous read operation (`fgets`) didn't reach the end of the input, so the second condition also succeeds.

```
    sscanf(buffer, "%f ", &a[x]);
```

Here in the loop body we call `sscanf` again, placing `50.0` into `a[0]` again.

```
    x++;
    }
```

Then we increment `x` (from 0 to 1) and restart the loop.

```
while(sscanf(buffer, "%f ", &a[x]) == 1 && !feof(stdin)){
```

The only thing that's changed is the value of `x`, so this time around we place `50.0` in `a[1]` and re-enter the loop body.

The loop body again overwrites `a[1]` with the same value it just scanned (`50.0`) and increments `x` to 2.

Then we restart the loop and place `50.0` in `a[2]`.

...

Then we restart the loop and place `50.0` in `a[3]`.

...

Then we restart the loop and place `50.0` in `a[4]`.

...

Then we restart the loop and place `50.0` in `a[5]`.

...

Then we restart the loop and place `50.0` in `a[6]`.

...

But wait! The last element of our array is `a[4]`. We've just written to `a[5]` and `a[6]`, which don't exist. This is an infinite loop that keeps writing to ever-increasing indices of `a`, going way out of bounds.

Comment: Oh, so I am rewriting the same value to every array position.. would adding another condition which limits x to stop at the array size value solve this? Also, would it be possible to read every float, one by one by increasing the array size, using fgets to read the whole input and utilizing sscanf to read the first float, strtok to find the first space, delete the first float and the space, whole string shifts, read the first one again (second value this time) and so on? Thank you for responding